# drupal_add_js only once

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a field which is used in a nodeblock, and only appears on a few select pages. This however will vary throughout the lifetime of the website so I've been looking for a way to insert the Javascript this field requires only when it's present. Additionally, the field can appear more than once on any given page.

Looking at `drupal_add_js`, I can't see that it provides a way to only include JS once. Using this I was hoping that I could just call it in the `field--field-name.tpl.php` file for that field but as it occurs multiple times, the JS is included more than once.

I've looked at the module JS Injector, but that's just page specific and just calls the aforementioned function. This wouldn't help me because every time a new block is added somewhere, the list of pages including the JS would also need to be updated.

Is there a way I can include a JS file just once in Drupal?

Comment: Are you familiar with the php `static` keyword? If not put that in on google, it's ideal for solving your problem

Comment: Are you trying to add a JS file once or some inline JS once?

Comment: A JS file once. @Clive I assume you mean something like `static $done; if(!$done) { drupal_add_js(); $done = true; }` ?

Comment: @Ben exactly :) although if you're adding files, Drupal will only add it once (the js array is keyed by the full path to the file to make absolutely sure of that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what type of javascript you are adding.

- [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) will only add *files* once, no matter how often it's called ;
- *Settings* would overwrite previous values, so it's not a major problem ;
- *Inline code* would indeed get added multiple times.

Given that your script needs including only once no matter how often the field is present, I assume you are not generating it's code on the fly - so putting it in a file would be an option.

Otherwise, as suggested by Clive, you could have your own wrapper around drupal_add_js that ensures a given inline js is only added once by using a static variable.

Comment: This is not strictly true. JavaScript settings don't overwrite previous values in Drupal 7 although it seems they now do in Drupal 8. https://www.drupal.org/node/1911578